# Changing rootViewController causing weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwindow, rootviewcontroller

I am setting rootViewController like this in my app.

```
func setupMainView() {
    let rootViewContorller = window?.rootViewController

    if (rootViewContorller?.presentedViewController != nil || rootViewContorller?.presentingViewController != nil) {
        rootViewContorller?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    let tabbarController = UITabBarController()
    tabbarController.delegate = self

    let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
    let rewardsViewController = RewardsViewController()

    let homeNVc = UINavigationController()
    let rewardsNVc = UINavigationController()

    homeNVc.viewControllers = [homeViewController]
    rewardsNVc.viewControllers = [rewardsViewController]

    tabbarController.viewControllers = []

    tabbarController.viewControllers = [homeNVc, rewardsNVc]
    tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0

    self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController
}
```

It is working fine. But I have to change rootViewController in the app like after registration etc. After that When I go to `Debug View Hierarchy` . I still see the registrationViewController there. And lets say If I change rootViewController 3-4 times all previous controllers are still there. So my question is How can I remove all viewControllers from memory before changing the rootViewController.

Comment: What if you set `rootViewController` to `nil` and then set it to whatever you like in the next line?

Comment: tried it already but its do nothing which i want. @LinusGeffarth

Comment: Can you please put the code how you are adding other view controller on window?

Comment: i am not adding any viewController on window but my "homeNVc" & "rewardsNVc" contain other viewControllers  @SauravNagpal

Comment: Can you please check is view controller is dismissed properly by comment out the code "self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController"

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function this will clear all viewcontrollers.

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```